# How to create user funnels for Mobile App in Bigquery?

Tags: sql, firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I am trying to build user funnels in Bigquery and I have reached the following state :

```
u1 e1 41  
u1 e1 42  
u2 e1 43  
u3 e1 44  
u1 e1 45  
u3 e1 46  
u4 e1 47  
u2 e1 48  
u4 e1 49  
u4 e1 50  

u1 e2 43  
u2 e2 44  
u4 e2 48  
u2 e2 49  
u3 e2 50  
u1 e2 51  
u3 e2 52  
u1 e2 53  
u2 e2 54  
u2 e2 55  
u1 e2 56
```

where `u1`,`u2` are userids, `e1`,`e2` are event names and `41`,`42`, `43` are event timestamps.

I used this query :

```
WITH Step1 AS (  
SELECT
user_dim.user_id as user_id1,  
event.timestamp_micros as event_timestamp1,  
DATETIME_DIFF(current_datetime(),  
DATETIME(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event.timestamp_micros)), DAY) as Days1,  
event.name AS Event_Name1  
FROM `com_xxx_android_ANDROID.app_events_*`,  
UNNEST(event_dim) AS event  
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(),  
INTERVAL 2 DAY))  
AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))   
AND event.name='PLDetailForm'  
ORDER BY Days1--,Event_Name1,user_id1  
),  
Step1_COUNT AS (  
select count(*) AS A from Step1  
),  
Step1_USERIDS AS (  
select user_id1 from Step1  
),  
Step1_USERS AS (  
select  COUNT(DISTINCT user_id1) as users from Step1  
),  
Step2 AS (  
SELECT  
user_dim.user_id as user_id2,  
event.timestamp_micros as event_timestamp2,  
DATETIME_DIFF(current_datetime(),   
DATETIME(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event.timestamp_micros)), DAY) as Days2,  
event.name AS Event_Name2    
FROM  
`com_xxx_android_ANDROID.app_events_*`,  
UNNEST(event_dim) AS event  
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(),   
INTERVAL 2 DAY))  
AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))   
AND event.name='PL_CONTINUE_PL_DETAILFORM'  
AND user_dim.user_id in (select * from Step1_USERIDS)  
ORDER BY Days2--,Event_Name2,user_id2  
--AND event.timestamp_micros>(select event_timestamp1 from Step1 where )  
),  
Step2_COUNT AS (  
select DISTINCT count(*) AS B from Step1,Step2 where   
step1.user_id1=step2.user_id2  
AND event_timestamp2>event_timestamp1  
),  
Step2_USERIDS AS (  
select user_id2 from Step2  
),  
Step2_USERS AS (  
select  COUNT(DISTINCT user_id2) as users from Step2  
)
```

I want to calculate how many users performed `e1` and then `e2`. How to accomplish that from the above data?

Comment: using example of data on top of your question - show expected result and explain better logic. do you mean e2 right after e1 or just anytime after e1 or any other logic